# How to display title on HTML elements by focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any Jquery or any other way to display the title of the elements on giving focus just as the title displayed on hovering???

I have found this jquery but its not working.....Can anyone help please... Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!!

```
$(function () {
    var xOffset = 20;
    var yOffset = 30;

    $('input').focus(function (e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        $("body").append("<span id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</span>");
        $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
    });

    $('input').blur(function (e) {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#tooltip").remove();

        $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: It makes no sense why on blur it positions the element that you removed from the document.

Answer (score 2):

`EL:focus::after { content: attr(title); }`

Should work. Look ma, no JS!

You just need to position the pseudo ::after element.

Mind this only works if the “pseudo parent” allows for a pseudo element.

Comment: <input> can't have a pseudo element unfortunately…

Comment: Thanks Matijs fr the solution...but I have focus elements also... wat can i do in that case??

Answer (score 1):

focus event has no x and y position. You need to use the element's offset

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery UI Tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/). It handles bubbling `mouseover`, `mouseleave`, `focusin`, `focusout` events on `document` by default. You just need to prevent mouse events propagation.

```js
$(document).tooltip();

// prevent mouse event, handle focus events only
$('input').on('mouseover mouseleave', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input title="tooltip" type="text" />
```